# Paper clip file upload issue in windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, image-upload

I got an issue when I tried to upload an image using the paperclip gem.
It is working fine on my ubuntu system but not on windows 10.
`Rails version = 5.1.2` `Ruby version = 2.2.6p396` `paperclip = 5.2.1`

> [paperclip] Trying to link C:/Users/.../Temp/c935d187f0b998ef720390f85014ed1e20180310-5860-1yxm99j.png to C
>   :/Users/.../Temp/c935d187f0b998ef720390f85014ed1e20180310-5860-1mjjyje.png
>   [paperclip] Link failed with File exists @ sys_fail2 - C:/Users/.../Temp/c935d187f0b998ef720390f85014ed1e20
>   180310-5860-1mjjyje.png; copying link C:/Users/.../Temp/c935d187f0b998ef720390f85014ed1e20180310-5860-1yxm9
>   9j.png to C:/Users/.../Temp/c935d187f0b998ef720390f85014ed1e20180310-5860-1mjjyje.png
>   Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/.../Temp/c935d187f0b998ef720390f85014ed1e20180310-5860-1mjjyje.png"
>   [paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename Dog.png (image/png from Headers, ["image/png"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see here:

> [paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename Dog.png (image/png from Headers, ["image/png"] from Extension), **content type discovered from file command: .** See documentation to allow this combination.

Paperclip (or more precisely `file -b --mime` command used to identify Content-Type) silently fails leaving you with empty string as a result.

It's working fine on Ubuntu because `file` program is included in your distribution (you can verify that by using commands like `man file` or `which file`). If you run `sudo apt remove file` on Ubuntu and then try to upload file it will result in error message same as above.

If you want to use Paperclip on Windows, according to [this section](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#file), you should install `file` manually and add path to your environment variable:

1. Download & install file from [this URL](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm)
2. Go to GnuWin32 directory and run `file.exe` to test it works.
3. [Add file.exe path to your PATH variable](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10) or add `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin` to your config/environments